# Link some cells in sheet 1 to cells in sheet 2 in same workbook

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aiyT.jpg): [image]
Dear all,

I have the two attached sheet files and I need your help to make a link between the cells in the sheet 1 to the cells in the sheet 2 in the same workbook.

Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you mean by link. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Only assistance we can give you right now is to wish you good luck to solve it! You haven't shown any effort- so we won't either.

Answer (score 0):

Just write `=` in cell in sheet2 and then pick whit the mouse the cell that you want to be equal in sheet1.

Comment: If I did not understand what you want to do please be more specific.